# Смена ориентации фрагментов в Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, orientation

Есть Активити в котором через ViewPager включаются два фрагмента.

В методе onCreate MainActivity я запускаю Service, поэтому каждый раз при смене ориентации перезапускать Service не хочется.

Вопрос в чем: Можно ли отлавливать смену ориентации и перерисовать только один единственный фрагмент, а не все приложение целиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для любой activity в тэге `<activity>` в `AndroidManifext.xml` можно указать список параметров конфигурации, которые не должны приводить к ее пересозданию. Для перехвата смены ориентации вам нужно:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Изменение конфигурации будет приходить в activity в метод `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`

Answer (score -1):

Я бы советовал отказаться от этой затеи и написать запуск или работу сервиса так, чтобы пересоздание активити ему не мешала. Проблема в том, что активити пересоздается не из-за смены ориентации, а из-за смены конфигурации, смена ориентации - далеко не единственная причина.